# Using AMPScript for changing salutations?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We are setting up an invitation for an event in Marketing Cloud and want to include in the message `%%salutation%% are invited to xx event` however if the salutation is a single name we would like to append and Partner to the name so it reads `%%salutation%% and Partner are invited to xx event`

Our salutation data field follows this format:

- Name
- Name, Name, Name
- Name and Name
- Name & Name

So if there is a comma, & or and then don't show "and partner"

Is this something you could do with AMPscript or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a conditional utilizing the [**indexOf**](https://ampscript.guide/indexOf) AMPscript function to determine if your salutation contains the words and punctuation you described:

```
%%[

  var @salutation, @salutationSuffix

  set @salutation = AttributeValue("salutation")
  set @salutationSuffix = " and partner"

  if indexOf(@salutation, ",") > 0 
     or indexOf(@salutation, " and ") > 0 
     or indexOf(@salutation, " & ") > 0 
     or indexOf(@salutation, " &amp; ") > 0
     or empty(@salutation) then 

     set @salutationSuffix = "" 

  endif 

  set @saluation = iif(empty(@salutation), "You ", @salutation)

]%%

%%=v(@salutation)=%%%%=v(@salutationSuffix)=%% are invited to xx event.
```

I think it'd also be good to include handling for salutations that are empty.  The [**iif**](https://ampscript.guide/iif) (inline-if) and [**empty**](https://ampscript.guide/empty) functions can be used for that.

Comment: Worked perfect, thanks